# How to remove the .isDefined in the following scala snippets

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

In a slick query I have:

```
def getAbc(userId: Option[Int], levelId: Option[Int]): List[User] = {
  val q = for {
      m <- users if m.approved &&
          userId.isDefined && m.userId ==== userId.get && levelId.isDefined && m.levelId === levelId.get
  } yield m
  q.list()
}
```

I don't like how I am using isDefined and .get in the above, how can I remove them?

```
val user: Option[User] = ....
if(user.isDefined) {
   val productSales:List[Product] = getProducts(user.get.id)
   val isBoss = (user.get.levelId.isDefined && (user.get.levelId.get == 10))

}
```

In the above, I have 2 levels if isDefined checks, how can I get around this type of pattern?

Comment: Note that `opt.isDefined && opt.get == x` is equivalent to `opt.exists(_ == x)`.

Comment: ... which is equivalent to `opt.contains(x)`, right?

Comment: @dhg Right, but that won't work with `===`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
scala> val userId = Some(1)
userId: Some[Int] = Some(1)

scala> val levelId = Some(2)
levelId: Some[Int] = Some(2)

scala> for { u <- userId
     |       l <- levelId
     |      q  = u + l  // This would be your query 
     |     } yield q 
res0: Option[Int] = Some(3)
```

Comment: The above shows how to avoid .isDefined and .get see Soumya Simanta Answer for the how and why.

Comment: thanks, but just to mention, I want to return a List[User] not an Option.

Comment: actually this doesn't work.  After the for comp. the q variable doesn't have the usual methods like q.sortBy and q.list()

Answer (score 1):

you can make use of for comprehension (as other answers stated above already) :

```
val q: Option[List[User]] = for {
    uId <- userId
    lvlId <- levelId
    m <- users 
    if m.approved && m.userId ==== uId && m.levelId === lvlId
} yield m

q.getOrElse(Nil)
```

and for the second one basically the same:

```
val levelCheck: Option[Int] = for {
    u <- user
    lvlId <- u.levelId
    if lvlId == 10
} yield lvlId

val isBoss: Boolean = levelCheck.isDefined
val productSales:List[Product] = user.map(u => getProducts(u.id)).getOrElse(Nil)
```

Comment: for the top query, it returns a List[User] not a Option[List[User]]

Comment: what do you mean by top query? or what is returning a `List[User]`?

Answer (score 0):

`Option` is a monad (e.g., - http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/7326)

so you can you use `map/flatMap/filter` or `for-yield`.

Here are some examples where you can perform operations without checking for `isDefined` or `get`.

```
scala> val a : Option[String] = Some("John")
a: Option[String] = Some(John)

scala> for( x <- a ) yield println(x)
John
res6: Option[Unit] = Some(())

scala> a.isDefined
res7: Boolean = true

scala> val b : Option[String] = None
b: Option[String] = None

scala> b.isDefined
res8: Boolean = false

scala> for ( x <- b ) yield print(x)
res9: Option[Unit] = None

scala> val names : List[Option[String]] = List(Some("John"), None, Some("James") )
names: List[Option[String]] = List(Some(John), None, Some(James))

scala> val validNames = for { name <- names; n <- name } yield { n }
validNames: List[String] = List(John, James)
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is a very helpful answer. There's no indication in the question that "`Option` is a monad" is going to be useful information to the OP, and listing a bunch of stuff you can do with `Option` isn't much better.

Comment: Why for (...) yield println? for () println would do, without creating unused (and unusable) result